# getting current date with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a variable that gets the current date and time so I can compare it to a deadline (ex: 7/30/12 23:23:10).  I put this code in a file called date.php and it is supposed to return a 10 digit number, but instead I get a server error.  Can anyone help me create a variable that gets the current time in php?

```
<?php
$date = date_create();
echo date_timestamp_get($date);
?>
```

Comment: Exactly what error message do you see? Also, in what format would you like the datetime: as a UNIX timestamp (integer) or as some kind of date string?

Comment: It just said server error...HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Hm. If PHP's error reporting isn't enabled, you're gonna have a bad time trying to debug… Maybe start there.

Comment: i want it as a 10 digit number similar to epoch so I can compare times so probably UNIX...

Comment: @FaceBook what thing you have used Is it webmatrix based IIS express or apache server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need such complicated functions.

```
echo date("r"); // Returns RFC 2822 formatted date.
echo time(); // Returns UNIX timestamp
```

See the PHP [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation for more on date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official date create doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date-create.php) date_create() only works with PHP 5.2.0 or higher.

Do you have PHP 5.2.0 ? (do a phpinfo())